# ClouldFormation AppFlow template to select a list of fields

Tags: amazon-s3, salesforce, aws-cloudformation, amazon-appflow

I am trying to create **AWS AppFlow Flow** using **CloudFormation** template.

In the AppFlow the source is **Salesforce** and destination in **AWS S3**.

There are two requirements:

1. Select all the fields from source to destination
2. Select a list of fields from source to destination

For the first requirement the following CloudFormation template was developed and able to successfully generate the AppFlow flow by creating the CloudFormation Stack.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  MySalesforceToS3Flow:
    Type: AWS::AppFlow::Flow
    Properties:
      FlowName: app_flow_name
      TriggerConfig:
        TriggerType: Scheduled
        TriggerProperties:
          DataPullMode: Incremental
          ScheduleExpression: rate(1days)
          ScheduleStartTime: epoch_time
      SourceFlowConfig:
        ConnectorType: Salesforce
        ConnectorProfileName: connection_name
        IncrementalPullConfig: 
          DatetimeTypeFieldName: field_name
        SourceConnectorProperties:
          Salesforce:
            Object: salesforce_object_name
      DestinationFlowConfigList:
        - ConnectorType: S3
          DestinationConnectorProperties:
            S3:
              BucketName: bucket_name
              S3OutputFormatConfig:
                PrefixConfig: 
                    PrefixFormat: DAY
                    PrefixType: PATH
                FileType: PARQUET
      Tasks:
        - TaskType: Map_all
          SourceFields: []
          TaskProperties:
          - Key: EXCLUDE_SOURCE_FIELDS_LIST
            Value: '[]'
          ConnectorOperator:
            Salesforce: NO_OP
```

When it comes to second requirement all we got is the list of field names.

I tried creating the template by updating the Tasks but the Stack creation is failure with different error.

Can someone help me in creating the template for list of field names.

**Note: The source and destination datatypes are not provided**